# JS code not working when loaded into jquery dialogue

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, keyword-search

i have some code that allows you to type a username (almost like the SO keywords) however when I load it into a jquery dialog modal, the search functionality for users stops working...

Im my header.php file I have the include to the js file..

this is the basic code snippet that stops working inside the dialog modal:

```
   <span class="font-heavy" id="">To:</span> 
   <input type="text" id="users" name="blah" placeholder="Add friends"/>
   <input type="hidden"  id="tags"/>


   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $("#users").tokenInput([
          {id: 44, name: "fstar55 burrens"},
          {id: 87, name: "fstars fishing supplies Burrens"}
          ],
           {
            prePopulate: [
            {id: 19, name: "Joe Soap"}

            ],theme: "facebook", preventDuplicates: true, 
              hintText: "Add friends"
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Ive tried loading it in different sequences but no luck. Not even the (no results) message comes up.. ive tried adding the includes to the js and css into the actual modal data - still no luck.

Im still learning about js - any ideas?

My header file includes:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/holder.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/token-input.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/token-input-facebook.css" type="text/css" />
```